# ASP.NET Web Application - publishing - not creating individual assembles (dlls) for each aspx page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web-applications, publishing, precompile

I have a ASP.NET Web Application in Vs2012.

While publishing locally, Visual studio is not generating individual assembles (Precompiled Dlls) for each Aspx page ( eg. App_Web_MyPage.aspx.someNumber.dll), instead it creates only the main Dll. If I do this on Web Site project, it generates. Both are having the same Advanced precompile settings.

I want to create individual Precompiled assembles (Dlls) for each aspx page in a WAP. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the asp.net merge tool is running automatically when you publish your site.  Take a look at the configuration options for publishing -> Advanced Precompile Settings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh475319(v=vs.110).aspx

We used to handle custom merge scenarios, in our continuous build, by adjusting our ant and msbuild files that were calling the compiler and merge tools directly for asp.net projects a few years ago.

Comment: I have checked the box "Allow precompiled site to be updatable". I removed that and now it is working fine. Thanks very much for your help.